# Using TDictionary "for...in"

Tags: delphi, dictionary

I am using Delphi Berlin 10.1 (the latest update) and I am having a problem with TDictionary in my application with some especific values. The "for..in" doesn't loop correctly.

Below there is a example code where the "for...in" doesn't loop through all values and another example where it does.

In the first case, the "for...in" loop does only two steps and in the second one it goes through all steps.

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  tmpPar: TPair<Integer, Integer>;
  tmpDictionary: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>;
begin
  // NOT WORKING
  tmpDictionary := TDictionary<Integer, Integer>.Create;
  try
      tmpDictionary.Add(631, 40832);
      tmpDictionary.Add(1312, 40837);
      tmpDictionary.Add(5947, 40842);

      for tmpPar in tmpDictionary do
      begin
          tmpDictionary.Remove(tmpPar.Key);
      end;
  finally
      tmpDictionary.Free;
  end;

  // WORKING
  tmpDictionary := TDictionary<Integer, Integer>.Create;
  try
      tmpDictionary.Add(123, 5432);
      tmpDictionary.Add(453, 23);
      tmpDictionary.Add(76, 2334);

      for tmpPar in tmpDictionary do
      begin
          tmpDictionary.Remove(tmpPar.Key);
      end;
  finally
      tmpDictionary.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Is there something wrong in the first case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Always loop from high index to low when deleting something from a collection (so long you cannot use a collection lock for this task). I bet this is related. That´s what `for..in` loop cannot offer you (as it goes internally forward).

Comment: In both cases, you should not modify an enumerable while you are enumerating it. You should build a list of keys to remove, then remove them. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627221/how-to-iterate-a-tdictionary-and-delete-item

Comment: tks for your reply, BUT why it never works in the first case and Always works in the second one?  I´ve made a code with VisualStudio (using C#) and worked well.. So, can be a compiler bug??

Comment: Because pairs that you iterate are sorted in a different way than you added them. I would just follow what @Blorgbeard said.

Comment: @Tiago It's not a bug, there should be no expectation that this works.

Comment: Are you *sure* it worked in C#? I would expect C# to give you a "Collection was modified" exception. E.g.: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vVnK52

Comment: This did not work in C# either. The items in the loop control the loop, and removing them while iterating them is simply wrong. Common sense should tell you that without even having to post here. You can't cut off the branch you're standing on when you're trimming a tree, or you end up on your back on the ground.

Comment: @Victoria: that is true for linear, indexed collections. That is not true when enumerating over a collection using for..in.

Comment: Why the RTL collections/enumerators don't have versioning to protect against this is beyond me. Oh - probably people would complain about the instance size because of that additional Integer field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J... gives the explanation. The easiest fix goes like this:

```
var
  tmpKey: Integer;                                //!!!amended
  tmpDictionary: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>;
begin
  // NOW WORKING
  tmpDictionary := TDictionary<Integer, Integer>.Create;
  try
      tmpDictionary.Add(631, 40832);
      tmpDictionary.Add(1312, 40837);
      tmpDictionary.Add(5947, 40842);

      for tmpKey in tmpDictionary.Keys.ToArray do //!!!amended
      begin
          tmpDictionary.Remove(tmpKey);           //!!!amended
      end;
  finally
      tmpDictionary.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Basically, calling Keys.ToArray gives you a fresh copy of the keys that won't get deleted from under its feet as you do the item deletions.

Comment: To be fair, this is a ridiculous construct.  If you're iterating over `tmpDictionary.Keys.ToArray` then you might as well just call `tmpDictionary.Clear()`.  The only sensible time to iterate for removal is when you are not removing *everything* from the dictionary but rather some subset.  In that case you need to build a secondary list of keys to remove as I said in my answer.

Comment: @J... - of course if you're going to be removing everything, Clear would be the best choice. I would assume the OP's real code only removes a value conditionally however, for which enumerating Keys.ToArray is perfectly reasonable. You don't need to manually 'build a secondary list of keys', as that's what Keys.ToArray exactly does, in a small-l sense of 'list'.

Comment: Had the same problem walking through values getting them deleted under my own feet, a simple values.toArray fixed it all. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Your example that works simply works by luck - there should be no expectation that this construct will behave well.  If you step through your example you see that the first case invokes list reordering upon removal but the second example does not.

To see what's going on, if you examine the code for removing items from a dictionary :

```
function TDictionary<TKey,TValue>.DoRemove(const Key: TKey; HashCode: Integer;
  Notification: TCollectionNotification): TValue;
var
  gap, index, hc, bucket: Integer;
  LKey: TKey;
begin
  index := GetBucketIndex(Key, HashCode);
  if index < 0 then
    Exit(Default(TValue));

  // Removing item from linear probe hash table is moderately
  // tricky. We need to fill in gaps, which will involve moving items
  // which may not even hash to the same location.
  // Knuth covers it well enough in Vol III. 6.4.; but beware, Algorithm R
  // (2nd ed) has a bug: step R4 should go to step R1, not R2 (already errata'd).
  // My version does linear probing forward, not backward, however.

  // gap refers to the hole that needs filling-in by shifting items down.
  // index searches for items that have been probed out of their slot,
  // but being careful not to move items if their bucket is between
  // our gap and our index (so that they'd be moved before their bucket).
  // We move the item at index into the gap, whereupon the new gap is
  // at the index. If the index hits a hole, then we're done.

  // If our load factor was exactly 1, we'll need to hit this hole
  // in order to terminate. Shouldn't normally be necessary, though.
  {...   etc   ...}
```

You see that there is an algorithm implemented which decides when and how to reorder the underlying list when removing items (this to attempt to optimize the location of gaps in the already-allocated memory block to optimize future insersions).  Enumerating simply moves through indices in the underlying list, so once you remove an item from the list the enumerator is no longer valid as it will simply move you to the next index in the underlying list, which has since changed.

For a plain list you would usually iterate in reverse when removing.  In the case of a dictionary, however, you must first build a list of keys to remove on the first enumeration pass and then enumerate *that* list to remove them from the dictionary.